Redirect Why doesn't clicking on log in send me to the AdminView or the UserView?
Repositorio git: https://github.com/Mejia2002/Proyecto_Wed_Segundo_Corte
The login is in the screens folder, where could the problem be?
I want when I click on the log in button to be redirected to the AdminView or the UserView depending on the Role, I am using React + firebase, I have not been able to identify where the problem is, if it is in the navigation or in the authentication.
When I click on the start session button I get "User Data: undefined" by console

Judging by your code it seems that userData.rol is not being set or retrieved in the way that you expect, try and console log that before doing your redirect, might give you some answers.

Como hago esto, con un console.log?
